# Pair of vector constructors: initializer list vs explicit construction

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, std-pair

I call the `std::pair<vector<int>, int>` constructor two ways:

- passing in an initializer list
- passing in an explicit vector (r-value).

For some reason, the initializer list version makes a copy (and destroys one). 
Here is my minimal code sample:

```
auto dummy() {
    return pair<vector<int>, int>{ {1,2,3,4,5}, 1};
}

auto dummy1() {
    return pair<vector<int>, int>{ vector{1,2,3,4,5}, 1};
}

auto dummy2() {
    return optional<vector<int> > { {1,2,3,4,5} };
}
```

After checking the compiler explorer, I found that the initializer list `dummy()` version calls `operator new` twice, and `delete` once. This happens with neither the explicit construction version `dummy1()` nor a similar `std::optional` constructor in `dummy2()`. I wouldn't expect this behavior. Does anyone know why? I checked with clang as well.

Comment: [Jason Turner -  “Initializer Lists Are Broken, Let's Fix Them”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSlmmZMFsXQ&t=3306s) can be very inspiring here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from `std::pair` constructors and template argument deduction / overload resolution:

```
pair( const T1& x, const T2& y ); // (1)

template< class U1, class U2 >
pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );           // (2)
```

Note that there is, at least, one "missing" constructor:

```
pair( T1&& x, T2&& y );           // (3)
```

When you use list-initialization for the first parameter, the selected constructor is not `(2)` (with `U1 = std::initializer_list<int>`) but `(1)`<sup>1</sup>. Thus, you need to construct a temporary `std::vector<int>`, which is passed as a `const`-reference to `(1)`, which has to make a copy.

You can confirm empirically this by either:

- creating your own `pair` with the third constructor mentioned above — in this case, `(3)` will be chosen, and the temporary `vector` will be moved;
- explicitly constructing an `std::initializer_list<int>` while constructing the `std::pair`:

```
pair<vector<int>, int>{ std::initializer_list<int>{1,2,3,4,5}, 1 };
```

On the other hand `std::optional` as a single templated constructor:

```
template < class U = value_type >
constexpr optional( U&& value );
```

...but there is a default value for `U`, which makes this constructor a valid candidate for overload resolution.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> When you call `pair{ {1,2,3,4,5}, 1 }`, `U1` is in a non-deduced context within `(2)` [[temp.deduct.type]#5.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#type-5.6), so deduction fails, which why `(1)` is selected.</sub>

Comment: Makes sense now. Would theoretically changing (2) to `template< class U1 = T1, class U2 = T2>` "fix" the problem? I'm surprised the standard doesn't have a matching constructor for brace initialization for `pair` elements.

Comment: @NarutSereewattanawoot I think it would yes.